# Integrating ASP.NET Security with Non-ASP.NET URLs & docx files

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application running on IIS6 (windows swrver 2003) and have successfully used the method described in this article: http://bit.ly/i78O7w to secure .jpg, .doc & .xls files in a directory named 'upload'.

I have now added .docx files to the directory but the browser returns a 404 when a docx is requested. The security still works.

Do I need to to make changes in web.config or in the Application Configuaration in IIS6?

web.config snippet:

```
<location path="upload">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Have you verified you can access the document when you've turned the security off?

Comment: Thanks - nope I couldn't - turns out I was missing the obvoious which was that I had to add the mime types for office 2007 to IIs6. Nothing to do with asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I was missing the obvoious which was that I had to add the mime types for office 2007 to IIs6. Nothing to do with asp.net